# How to solve #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: performance, phpmyadmin

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvekd.png)
I want to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(idu) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

But I get this error: `#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.`

Thank in advance.

Comment: Do your tables have data in them already?  Does any value in that `user_id` field not have a corresponding key value in the `users` table?

Comment: Yes my tables have data in them and user_id have a corresponding key value in the users table the column name is idu

Comment: *"user_id have a corresponding key value in the users table"* - The error message seems to imply otherwise.  What happens when you try to add this foreign key on the same tables but without any data in them?  How many rows are in them?  How have you verified that every row has a corresponding key in the target table?

Comment: I have 18 rows in my posts table and 11 rows in my users table .But the thing is all the posts that i have in the posts table are created by by a user existing in the users table ,i mean the user_id in posts has the same value as the idu in the users table.

Comment: Can you show the data in your question?

Comment: Ok, please i have made screen shot of the two tables but don't jnow to how uplaod the pictures so that can see them.And i am not allowed to more than one question.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is I had to remove data from the tables(posts and users) and eventually try the requet, it worked perfectly,I should do it as soon as I created the two tables before filling them of data.Thank you David for your replays.